# Unity 3D game using accelorometer sensor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am developing a virtual reality windows based game. I will be using an accelerometer sensor to get the hand movements of the player and use it in the game, where as the player will use it to fight an enemy in the game. I managed to get the accelerometer readings from the sensor.

I just need an idea on how I can now integrate it with my game in Unity. I used .Net to get the readings from the sensor. This is a TI simple link sensor tag (CC2650STK). This will connect via Bluetooth to my Windows phone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Buffer = Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer;

namespace SensorTag
{
    /// This class provides access to the SensorTag Accelerometer BLE data

    public class BleAccelerometerService : BleGenericGattService
    {

        public BleAccelerometerService() 
        {
        }


        /// The version of the SensorTag device.  1=CC2541, 2=CC2650.

        public int Version { get; set; }

        static Guid AccelerometerServiceUuid = Guid.Parse("f000aa10-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
        static Guid AccelerometerCharacteristicUuid = Guid.Parse("f000aa11-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
        static Guid AccelerometerCharacteristicConfigUuid = Guid.Parse("f000aa12-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
        static Guid AccelerometerCharacteristicPeriodUuid = Guid.Parse("f000aa13-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

        Delegate _accelerometerValueChanged;

        public event EventHandler<AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs> AccelerometerMeasurementValueChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (_accelerometerValueChanged != null)
                {
                    _accelerometerValueChanged = Delegate.Combine(_accelerometerValueChanged, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    _accelerometerValueChanged = value;
                    RegisterForValueChangeEvents(AccelerometerCharacteristicUuid);
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                if (_accelerometerValueChanged != null)
                {
                    _accelerometerValueChanged = Delegate.Remove(_accelerometerValueChanged, value);
                    if (_accelerometerValueChanged == null)
                    {
                        UnregisterForValueChangeEvents(AccelerometerCharacteristicUuid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<int> GetConfig()
        {
            var ch = GetCharacteristic(AccelerometerCharacteristicConfigUuid);
            if (ch != null)
            {
                var properties = ch.CharacteristicProperties;

                if ((properties & GattCharacteristicProperties.Read) != 0)
                {
                    var result = await ch.ReadValueAsync();
                    IBuffer buffer = result.Value;
                    DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                    var value = reader.ReadByte();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Acceleration config = " + value);
                    return (int)value;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        bool isReading;

        public async Task StartReading()
        {
            if (!isReading)
            {
                await WriteCharacteristicByte(AccelerometerCharacteristicConfigUuid, 1);
                isReading = true;
            }
        }

        public async Task StopReading()
        {
            if (isReading)
            {
                isReading = false;
                await WriteCharacteristicByte(AccelerometerCharacteristicConfigUuid, 0);
            }
        }


        /// Get the rate at which accelerometer is being polled, in milliseconds.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the value read from the sensor or -1 if something goes wrong.</returns>
        public async Task<int> GetPeriod()
        {
            byte v = await ReadCharacteristicByte(AccelerometerCharacteristicPeriodUuid, Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            return (int)(v * 10);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the rate at which accelerometer is being polled, in milliseconds.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="milliseconds">The delay between updates, accurate only to 10ms intervals. Maximum value is 2550.</param>
        public async Task SetPeriod(int milliseconds)
        {
            int delay = milliseconds / 10;
            byte p = (byte)delay;
            if (p < 1)
            {
                p = 1;
            }

            await WriteCharacteristicByte(AccelerometerCharacteristicPeriodUuid, p);
        }

        private void OnAccelerationMeasurementValueChanged(AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_accelerometerValueChanged != null)
            {
                ((EventHandler<AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs>)_accelerometerValueChanged)(this, args);
            }
        }


        public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(string deviceContainerId)
        {
            return await this.ConnectAsync(AccelerometerServiceUuid, deviceContainerId);
        }

        protected override void OnCharacteristicValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (sender.Uuid == AccelerometerCharacteristicUuid)
            {
                if (_accelerometerValueChanged != null)
                {
                    uint dataLength = eventArgs.CharacteristicValue.Length;
                    using (DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(eventArgs.CharacteristicValue))
                    {
                        if (dataLength == 3)
                        {
                            var data = new byte[dataLength];
                            reader.ReadBytes(data);

                            AccelerometerMeasurement measurement = new AccelerometerMeasurement();

                            sbyte x = (sbyte)data[0];
                            sbyte y = (sbyte)data[1];
                            sbyte z = (sbyte)data[2];

                            measurement.X = (double)x / 64.0;
                            measurement.Y = (double)y / 64.0;
                            measurement.Z = (double)z / 64.0;

                            OnAccelerationMeasurementValueChanged(new AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs(measurement, eventArgs.Timestamp));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class AccelerometerMeasurement
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set X accelerometer in units of 1 g (9.81 m/s^2).
        /// </summary>
        public double X { get; set;}   

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set Y accelerometer in units of 1 g (9.81 m/s^2).
        /// </summary>
        public double Y { get; set;}        

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set Z accelerometer in units of 1 g (9.81 m/s^2).
        /// </summary>
        public double Z { get; set;}

        public AccelerometerMeasurement()
        {
        }

    }

    public class AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public AccelerometerMeasurementEventArgs(AccelerometerMeasurement measurement, DateTimeOffset timestamp)
        {
            Measurement = measurement;
            Timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public AccelerometerMeasurement Measurement
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One requirement would be to convert the acceleration values into quaternion:

```
private void ReadAcceleration(AccelerometerMeasurement measure){
    Vector3 accel = new Vector3((float)measure.X, 
            (float)measure.Y, (float)measure.Z);
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(accel,Vector3.forward);
}
```

The rotation quaternion can be used to set an object to the device rotation.